# Functional Programming with Ramda: Can you curry a function that takes unlimited number of arguments

Tags: functional-programming, currying, ramda.js

Let's say I have 3 arrays

```
var first = [0, 1, 2, 3];
var second = [0, 1, 2, 3];
var third = [0, 1, 2, 3];
```

I would like to make a curried function where I set the first argument indicating which cell I would like to add amongst the arrays passed as arguments...ideally I would like the function to be able to take unlimited number of arrays....

For example:
`mycurriedfunction(1)` would mean I would like to access the value at cell 1 of the arrays I pass in and add them together.

Therefore doing:

`mycurriedfunction(1)(first)`  would return 1

`mycurriedfunction(1)(first)(second)` would return 2

`mycurriedfunction(2)(first)(second)(third)` would return 6

Is this even possible?

If not, then what alternative options are there for achieving a similar or even the same result?

Comment: So you need executable number type? You can try this: http://jsbin.com/xupaha/edit?js,console

Comment: This would be straightforward: `myFn(2, [first, second, third])`.  But your API is impossible.  The simulation from @iofjuupasli is probably the best you can do, but it's not particularly close.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others have mentioned, the function you describe would have no way of knowing whether to return the next function to call or the final value.

If you really want to achieve something similar that accepts an unbounded number of arrays, you could adapt it slightly to store the accumulated value as a property of the returned function.

```
function sumIdx(idx) {
  function f(value) {
    function g(arr) {
      return f(value + arr[idx]);
    }
    g.value = value;
    return g;
  }
  return f(0);
}
```

This can be used like your example, with the difference being that you need to pull the result off the `value` property when you're done.

```
const first  = [0, 1, 2];
const second = [3, 4, 5];
const third  = [6, 7, 8];

sumIdx(2)(first)(second)(third).value // 15
```

While possible, I probably wouldn't recommend using this approach. Perhaps using a separate data type would be better at representing this behaviour (or changing your API as Scott Sauyet suggested to `myFn(2, [first, second, third])`).

```
class SumIdx {
  constructor(idx, value) {
    this.idx = idx;
    this.value = value;
  }
  next(arr) {
    return new SumIdx(this.idx, this.value + arr[this.idx]);
  }
}

const sumIdx = idx => new SumIdx(idx, 0);
```

The difference here is that you need to call the `next` method rather than calling the result directly.

```
sumIdx(2).next(first).next(second).next(third).value // 15
```

Comment: You just prescribed poison to someone that trusted you

Answer (score 4):

No, it's not possible for a value to be both a number and a function.

You should make your function take a list instead, or be formulated as a reducer.